# ASP.NET MVC 4 Date Validation with DataAnnotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I need to validate 2 dates: "begin date" and "end date". "Begin date" must from today to the future and "end date" must be equal or greater than "Begin date". How can I do it with Data Annotations? Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked into custom validation attributes?

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2012_01_01_archive.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887824/greater-than-or-equal-to-today-date-validation-annotation-in-mvc3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577777/mvc-validation-lower-higher-than-other-value, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882296/mvc4-data-annotation-compare-two-dates, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025198/mvc-custom-validation-compare-two-dates

Comment: I have this custom validation attribute:
    public class MyDate1Attribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            return d >= DateTime.Today;
        }
    }
but I get this error: Error 1 'Dominio.elm' does not implement interface member 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject.Validate(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext)' C:\Users\baptista_l1\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ELM2\Dominio\elm.cs

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `DataAnnotations` as mentioned in bellow links:

1. [Greater Than or Equal To Today Date validation annotation in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887824/greater-than-or-equal-to-today-date-validation-annotation-in-mvc3)
2. [MVC Validation Lower/Higher than other value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577777/mvc-validation-lower-higher-than-other-value)
3. [mvc4 data annotation compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882296/mvc4-data-annotation-compare-two-dates)
4. [MVC custom validation: compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025198/mvc-custom-validation-compare-two-dates)

**But**, as an advice, solve this via Javascript libraries that are more easy than `DataAnnotation`s like [Jquery Input Mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)

Comment: Client-side Validation (like Jquery input Mask) is great, but always check server-side too .. ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/15855799/130420 )