# MVC startdate and end date validations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am having difficulties getting this to work. I want to allow a user to choose `start date` and `end date`, if the `start date` is greater than the `end date` I want an error message to display. I am using `MVC`. This is the code I have on my model.

```
 public class ModelClass : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID Number is required")]
    [Display(Name = "ID Number:")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{13})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a 13 digit ID number")]
    public Int64 ID_Number { get; set; }
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "The start date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date:")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The end date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "End Date:")]
    [GreaterThan("Start_Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime End_Date { get; set; }





    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (End_Date < Start_Date)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("EndDate must be greater than StartDate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably need a custom validation like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887824/greater-than-or-equal-to-today-date-validation-annotation-in-mvc3) here.

Answer (score 8):

This is how your model should look like:

```
 public class ModelClass : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID Number is required")]
    [Display(Name = "ID Number:")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{13})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a 13 digit ID number")]
    public Int64 ID_Number { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The start date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date:")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The end date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "End Date:")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime End_Date { get; set; }


    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (End_Date < Start_Date)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("EndDate must be greater than StartDate");
        }
    }
}
```

After the user pressed on the submit button we need to check that the model is valid.

> ModelState.IsValid

will go to you model and will validate the model, If the post model is valid(keeping the rules you decided in your model) then it's valid.

And this is how your action should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ModelClass modelClass)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.modelClass.Add(modelClass);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(modelClass);
}
```

Comment: i did that, when i submit it doesnt validate even when the end date is less than the start date